# Printing more than one field

Tags: text-processing, awk

Is there a way to print multiple fields with a single line command?

I want to print $3 to $NF, I can do it like below:

```
awk -F[:] '{print $3,$4,$5 .... $NF}'
```

Yet it is not doable with large number of fields and it is prone to errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I know is to loop over each field:

```
$ echo "a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i" | 
    awk -F":" '{for(i=3;i<=NF-1;i++){printf "%s ", $i}print $NF}'
c d e f g h i
```

Alternatively, you could just use `perl`:

```
$ echo "a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i" | perl -F":" -lane 'print "@F[2..$#F]"'
c d e f g h i
```

Or `cut`:

```
$ echo "a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i" | cut -d: -f3- 
c:d:e:f:g:h:i
```

Or `sed`:

```
$ echo "a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i" | sed 's/\([^:]*:\)\{2\}//'
c:d:e:f:g:h:i
```

Comment: this is like that chat we had that time. you should add one of those `sed` things, too. i could swear, though, that there was a better way with `awk` in that chat. why not just delete fields 1,2 and print the whole line?

Comment: @mikeserv you're probably thinking of `awk -F":" '$1=$2"";1;'` but that includes leading spaces (because a space, the value of `OFS`, is printed even if the fields are empty). You can avoid that by setting `OFS` to empty but then the fields are mashed together. You can get around that too but by this point it's much simpler to just loop over the fields. I added a `sed` one.

Comment: looks good. i didnt know that about awk. another way with `sed` is to skip whole field counts. you can split a pattern space with newlines and chomp it down with `D` and/or `P`. like: `sed -et -e's/:/\n/2;D'`. but `cut` is better.