# print field that contain a certain value

Tags: text-processing, awk

is it possible to print the field that contain a certain value?

Consider below file:

```
foo,boo,123,1234312,ABC
foo,boo,ABC,bla,bla
```

There is a field that contain `ABC` but it is not a fixed with all records, so the command need to print `$5` in the first record and `$3` in the second one.

Comment: It sounds to me like this could be simplified to `grep -q ABC file && echo ABC` ?

Comment: What you described is print `ABC`  if record contains `ABC`. Is this what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just like in your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233677/22222), but match each field:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/ABC/){print $i}}}' file
ABC
ABC
```

Note that the above will also print a filed that *contains* `ABC`, like `fooABC` or `fooABCbar` or whatever. To print only fields that *are* `ABC`, use:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="ABC"){print $i}}}' file
```

The same thing, in Perl:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print grep{/ABC/}@F' file     ## field matches
perl -F, -lane 'print grep{$_=="ABC"}@F' file ## field is
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with PCRE (Perl Compatible RegEx):

```
grep -Po '(?<=^|,)ABC(?=,|$)' file.txt
```

Comment: For most cases is enough '\bABC\b' regexp